Cola de Baja Calidad - No existe una opción que convenga, debo omitir?
no se si todos puedan ver esto como tal, asi que dejaré el link y la imagen más abajo (si no hay que dar alguna de estas, quitarla por favor, o la quito manualmente). 
Link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/412100
Pues bien, en la cola de baja calidad me aparece una respuesta la cual, a mi parecer "ya se han encargado de ella" y por ende requiere solamente eliminarla de la cola de reportes. Pero no tengo una opción que haga esto, solamente tengo:

Se ve bien: Marca la respuesta como "no es de baja calidad" quitando el reporte.
Editar: Me permite editar la respuesta yo mismo.
Recomendar eliminación: Elimina la respuesta y la quita del reporte.

Según mi solución, la opción correcta es: "Esta publicación ha sido revisada, y queda a la espera de una intervención". Lo cuál es la cuarta opción según ¿Cómo utilizo la cola de Publicaciones de baja calidad? pero parece que esta opción no existe para las respuestas. 
A mi parecer, ninguna las opciones anteriores atiende a que:

Alguien ya se ha encargado de corregir al usuario que responde
El reporte debe ser quitado de la cola de baja calidad, pero la respuesta aun es de baja calidad
Posible continuación de la 2 -> Si la respuesta no ha sido atendida por el usuario, debería eliminarse automáticamente, para el resto, pero no para el usuario que responde, quien debe saber que su respuesta ha sido reportada, y espera una mejora.

Actualmente creo que la única opción, debido a que han pasado 25 días, es la de "recomendar eliminación", lo cuál me parece injusto para quien ha respondido, y quien ha corregido al usuario que responde. La opción correcta es "cerrar" la respuesta, y que no sea visible hasta ser modificada nuevamente.


Sé que no tiene que ver pero, por qué escribes ah en vez de ha? Parece que estuvieras asustado/pidiendo ayuda

ah! dislexia jaja nisiquiera me doy cuenta cuando escribo uno u otro, solo lo noto una vez me corrigen, o me corrigo yo mismo, por eso evito usar correctores al momento de escribir. BTW @Mateo esa consulta me la puedes hacer por el chat para que no sea fuera de tema jaja

para eso existe el boton OMITIR.. omitir es tu amigo.. si no hay nada que hacer, o te da dudas, OMITIR

otra cosa.. justamente, no se encargaron de ella.. dejaron un comentario y OP no arreglo nada...
